# Show that $M:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n~|~ \Vert x-a\Vert \leq \delta\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Let's consider the following problem:

We want to show that $M:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n~|~ \Vert x-a\Vert \leq \delta\}\neq\emptyset$ is closed. According to our definition:

> A set $M$ is closed iff $M$ contains all its limit points.

Let be $b$ a limit point of $M$. Then we find a point $x\in M$ with $x \neq b$ in every neigbourhood. So for every $\epsilon>0$ the open ball $U_{\epsilon}(b):=\{x\in M~|~ \Vert x-b\Vert < \epsilon\}$ is non empty and contains a point $x\neq b$. Then we let $\epsilon \to 0$ and simply  conclude: $\Vert b-a\Vert = \Vert b-x+x-a\Vert \leq \Vert b-x \Vert+\Vert x-a\Vert\leq 0 + \delta$ which shows that $b\in M$. Hence, $M$ is closed as $b$ was arbitrarily chosen.

Actually this seems to me like a typical analysis technique but I am not sure if I have a wrong intuition in my mind or maybe the reasoning above is wrong?

In my mind $\epsilon$ will never reach $0$ it will only be very very close to it so that $\Vert b-x \Vert$ also will never become $0$. So following this logic the inequality above must be wrong?! May be someone can help me with this confusion.

Comment: If $||b-x||+||x-a||\lt\epsilon+\delta$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $||b-a||+||x-a||\le\delta$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, isn't it a contradiction to Paul's answer?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, hmm then I don't understand your first comment. Can you explain it a little bit more? How does it help if I know that $\Vert b-a\Vert + \Vert x-a\Vert\leq\delta$?

Comment: then $||b-a||\le\delta$, so the limit point $b$ is in $M$, so $M$ is closed

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, may be it's already too late but I don't see how it is possible to conclude $\Vert b-a\Vert\leq \delta$ from the inequalities you have used.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, so you are trying to conclude $\Vert b-a\Vert\leq\Vert b-x\Vert +\Vert x-a\Vert\leq \delta$, right? But according to Paul's answer this would be inadmissable.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I think Paul Frost is right, because the case when $\Vert b-x\Vert=0$ is excluded as $b\neq x$. It will always be $0<\Vert b-x\Vert <\epsilon$.

Comment: I am concluding from $||b-a||\le|b-x||+||x-a||\le\epsilon+\delta$ for all $\epsilon\gt0$ that $||b-a||\le\delta$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes I understand what you are trying to conclude. However, the reason why you draw this conclusion is not clear to me. Either you use the same argument José Carlos Santos has applied or something else which I am not aware of. May be you can explain why you are allowed to conclude $\Vert b-a\Vert \leq \delta$ from $\Vert b-a\Vert \leq \Vert b-x\Vert+\Vert x-a\Vert\leq\epsilon+\delta$?

Comment: In my last comment, I meant $\color{red}<\epsilon+\delta$, and see my answer below for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree that we can say “we let $\varepsilon\to0$”. I would do that proof as follows: take $\varepsilon>0$. There is some $x\in M$ such that $\|b-x_\varepsilon\|<\varepsilon$. So,$$\|b-a\|\leqslant\|b-x_\varepsilon\|+\|x_\varepsilon-a\|<\delta+\varepsilon.$$Since this occurs for each $\varepsilon>0$, then$$\|b-a\|\leqslant\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\delta+\varepsilon=\delta.$$Note that at no point I took $\varepsilon=0$.

Comment: I think my problem was that I haven't properly applied the rules of limits. If we consider for example $f(\epsilon)\leq g(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon$ then we have $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} f(\epsilon)\leq \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0} g(\epsilon)$. If we replace $f(\epsilon)$ by $\Vert b-a\Vert$ and $g(\epsilon)$ by $(\delta + \epsilon)$ then it is basically what you did, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have $||b-a||\le||b-x||+||x-a||\lt\epsilon+\delta$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

I claim then $||b-a||\le\delta$,

because otherwise we'd have $||b-a||>\delta$, and then $\epsilon=||b-a||-\delta>0$, and

then $||b-a||=\epsilon+\delta$, so it would not be true that $||b-a||\lt\epsilon+\delta$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: thank you for adding the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Your argument $\Vert b-x \Vert+\Vert x-a\Vert\leq 0 + \delta$ is inadmissible because $b \ne x$.

Assume $\Vert b-a\Vert >\delta$. Then take $\epsilon = \Vert b-a\Vert -\delta > 0$ and conclude
$$\Vert b-a\Vert = \Vert b-x+x-a\Vert \leq \Vert b-x \Vert+\Vert x-a\Vert < \epsilon + \delta = \Vert b-a\Vert$$
which is a contradiction.